# What's the difference between *quisquis* and *quicumque*?

Tags: idiom, syntax, word-comparison, pronouns

*Quisquis* and *quicumque* are both described as indefinite (or generic) relative pronouns, and are both defined in dictionaries as "whoever, everyone who...". Is there any difference at all between the two pronouns -- functionally, or in terms of idiom or period?

Comment: *Constituent Syntax*, by Philip Baldi, seems to answer this question in an extended passage beginning on pp. 105, but unfortunately pp. 106-7 and 113-4, so I'm not able to use it to answer your question.

Comment: @JoelDerfner Thanks. Baldi does say (105) that traditional grammars claim that *quisquis* is generally substantival, *quicumque* adjectival (which has been my assumption too), but then goes on to say that things are more complicated... (Btw I think your comment is missing something like "are not available for Google preview".) From reading around the hidden pages my guess is that Baldi thinks *quisquis* is about irrelevance/free choice of referent while *quicumque* is about universality (all things such that...), but that the uses start to merge already in Cicero's time.

Comment: Okay, it turns out it's a chapter in volume 3 of *Constituent Syntax*, which is a collection *edited* by Philip Baldi. The article itself is called "Quantification" and is by Alessandra Bertocchi, Mirka Maraldi, and Anna Orlandini. Unfortunately, I can't make hide or hair of it. I'll email it to you if you like.

Comment: @JoelDerfner Actually I would like to read that! My email is tkrstackexchange at gmail.com. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, after taking some time away and coming back to it, I get a pretty clear understanding that [Bertocchi, Maraldi, and Orlandini](https://books.google.com/books?id=6ClqWu9CMQ0C&pg=PA109&lpg=PA109&dq=cicero+quisquis+quicumque&source=bl&ots=J75f0P01IN&sig=ajlo0BcxHRMqv8MoIiFzccH3mzs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjVsJrij7bLAhUEPD4KHbB-DzcQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=cicero%20quisquis%20quicumque&f=false) say that before Cicero, "quicumque" usually means "all, every," but that in Cicero it begins to overlap with "quisquis" in meaning "whoever."

Answer (score 5):

Well, according to Gildersleeve, p. 59, *quisquis* is a noun and *quicumque* is an adjective.

> *Quisquis* is occasionally used as an adjective, but not in classical Latin. Occasionally, also, but rarely in Cicero, it is used for *quisque, quidque*.

The fact that he says this (while saying nothing in the same vein about *quicumque*) suggests to me that the reverse is *not* true—that, in fact, *quicumque* is used as both an adjective and a noun.

Comment: [Here's some more discussion](https://books.google.com/books?id=1YoAAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA195&lpg=PA195&dq=quisquis+vs.+quicumque&source=bl&ots=QC7aPY31_-&sig=gx1_8Zr5GKOljuDvw2WvMMsxV3g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjqy-Xp66LLAhWogYMKHQw_Bh4Q6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=quisquis%20vs.%20quicumque&f=false) backing this up more explicitly.