# Is there a difference between -vis and -libet?

Tags: word-comparison, pronouns, suffixes

The pronouns *quivis* and *quilibet* both mean "anyone", and *utervis* and *uterlibet* both mean "either one".
The suffixes *-vis* and *-libet* seem to have a pretty similar effect.
(I am not sure if there are other pronouns than *qui* and *uter* that can take both of these suffixes.)
Is there any difference between the two, or are they completely interchangeable?

Comment: I found [this old related question](http://latin.stackexchange.com/q/1390/79) today. I had forgotten I had asked it, but it's not a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're fairly interchangeable. Gildersleeve and Lodge even lump them together. Even in English, the literal translations would also be nigh indistinguishable.

> whichever you like
>
> whichever you want

Some grammars will sometimes add little nuances. [Smith](https://books.google.com/books?id=-vMsAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA37#v=onepage&q&f=false), for example, says that *quivis* is more deliberate than *quilibet*, where the latter has more of a force of "anyone at all, but [*quivis*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dquivis) can mean the same.

Comment: I don't think there's anything else to be said!